# Save values for each iteration of for-statement with if else in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

My problem: I have an if else-statement nested in an for-loop and want to save the values for each iteration of it.

For example with some simple data, what i've tried is:

```
s <- c(4, 8, 3) #a string with some values
l <- list() #the list where i want the output to be saved in
for (n in 1:length(s)) {
     if (n==1) {
         b1 <- 1:s[n]
         print(b1)
         l <- c(b1)} 
      else {
          b2 <- (s[n-1]:s[n])
          print(b2)
          l <- c(b1=b1, b2=b2)}}
```

The print() output is all vectors i want to save

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
[1] 8 7 6 5 4 3
```

but l only stores the first vector (from the if statement) and the last iteration of the else statement:

```
b11 b12 b13 b14 b21 b22 b23 b24 b25 b26 
  1   2   3   4   8   7   6   5   4   3
```

How can i save every iteration? I've been trying this for some hours and got nowhere, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to save results, you actually have to put them in the list rather than overwriting it, so you can do `l[[n]] <- b1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s <- c(4, 8, 3) #a string with some values
l <- list() #the list where i want the output to be saved in
for (n in 1:length(s)) {
    if (n==1) {
        b1 <- 1:s[n]
        print(b1)
        l[[length(l)+1]] <- c(b1)
    } 
    else {
        b2 <- (s[n-1]:s[n])
        print(b2)
        l[[length(l)+1]] <- b2
    }
}

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8

# [[3]]
# [1] 8 7 6 5 4 3
```

Comment: Ahhh never mind. Vectors are different lengths. . . fair enough